# Ionic 3 Notification

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, notifications, ionic3

I want to use notification with my app. I have checked ionic native and find some information.

First;

[Local Notification](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/)

Second;

[Push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/)

What do I want to do? I am using MySQL Database and I have two tables `users` and `points`. When I add points for one user, I want to send notification for only this user. How can I do this? Which can I use service?

Comment: This might help http://ionicguru.blogspot.com/2015/12/send-push-notification-to-specific-user.html

Answer (score 2):

As per your required I suggest you to use Push Notifications using FCM.
push notifications help to send notification into two or more ionic apps.

please follow these steps.

1. go to 'http://console.firebase.google.com' and create an android app make sure that app package name also mention in config.xml file.
2. Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins in App:

   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
   npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm
3. use this code in your 'app.component.ts' file with in initializeApp

/*getToken generates a device token that helps you to send notification on this device.you have to store this token in your database when app is open.*/

```
fcm.getToken().then(token=>{
    console.log(token);
  });
fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{
  if(data.wasTapped){
    console.log("Received in background");
  } else {
    console.log("Received in foreground");
  };
});
fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token=>{
  console.log(token);
});
```

4. Now the real process that you have to follow for send notification

   /*here is you have to add device token that is you have store in your database and your firebase api key.*/

   ```
   let body = {
   "notification":{
       "title":"New Notification has arrived",
       "body":"Notification Body",
       "sound":"default",
       "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
       "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
   },
   "data":{
       "param1":"value1",
       "param2":"value2"
   },
   "to":"Device token/ID",
   "priority":"high",
   "restricted_package_name":""
   }
   let options = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
   this.http.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",body,{
       headers: options.set('Authorization', 'key=YourAuthToken'),
   }).subscribe();
   ```

hope this is helpful for you.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

**Push notification** works the same way as local notification with a minor difference. Push notifications require connectivity and a server infrastructure of some kind to send the notification. With **local notification** you can trigger the notification with conditions. You will get the notification even if the app is closed and you’re offline. And having both notifications won’t cause implications.

***In your case, you should go with Push Notification.If in future if you want to change the parameter to send notification it will be easy for you to maintain.No need to update the app***

You can use FCM- Firebase Cloud Messaging on server side and in client side you can use PhoneGap push plugins to generate device token

here are the plugins

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="1.8.4">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your information, we are using push OK. There is two questions,
1. How can i do this ?
2. which can i use service ?
You have answered second question, and please answer first question

Comment: i already using user push notification. i can setup with FCM push. its working no problem. _**But i want to send push when i added information to MySQL database**_